# CSS hover image not working on Firefox but works on Chrome

Tags: css

CSS hover image not working on Firefox but works on Chrome

These are my codes.

```
.col-md-2 .angelhack {
height: 65px;
width: 188px;
content: url(../img2/logo_angelhack.png);
```

}

```
.col-md-2 .angelhack:hover {
    height: 65px;
    width: 188px;
    content: url(../img2/logo_angelhack_colored.png);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing 'content' to 'background-image' in your CSS. Quotes around the image path are optional:

```
background-image: url(../img2/logo_angelhack.png);
```

I've added an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dKcdK/

Note that the example assumes that `.angelhack` is a block level element. If that's not the case, then you'll need to also apply `display: block;` in your CSS.

*Given the comments below containing your HTML, I would remove the image tag from the source HTML entirely, and set your `class="angelhack"` on the anchor tag. Then add `display: block;` in the CSS.

Updated jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dKcdK/2/

Comment: Interesting. One moment, I'll set up a jsFiddle for testing / examples.

Comment: What kind of element is '.angelhack'? If it's inline by default, then you'll need to give it display: block; in your CSS.

Comment: I don't know why it works in Chrome, but the explanation for this is that you can't use the `content` attribute with the `:hover` selector. `content` is meant for `:before`/`:after` pseudo elements.

Comment: @JoshC yes I read that a while ago about content I don't really know why it works on Chrome but not on Firefox. I've tried also other similar questions here but it doesn't work :(

Comment: <div class="col-md-2">
              <a href="http://blog.angelhack.com/post/58276267607/introducing-angelhack-hackcelerator-team-pagesnapp" target="_blank"><img class="angelhack" src="/static/img2/logo_angelhack.png" alt="Native" /></a> </div>                                                                                   @StuartKershaw this are my html codes, sorry I'm still new to stackoverflow I don't know how to arrange the html codes on comment.

Comment: Ah, so the element in question is an image? It appears that you're trying to set a background image on an image tag. In that case, the image itself will occupy the foreground and block the background effect from coming through.

Comment: Yes the element I'm trying to put hover is an image which class="angelhack"  It pretty works on Chrome but not on firefox :(

Comment: @StuartKershaw yes your right, that's the result I got after testing the background-image code.

Comment: Does your image contain transparency? Or is it solid?

Comment: @StuartKershaw it's solid image from grayscale image to colored image when it's hover.

Comment: I think you should remove the image from the source markup HTML, and let the CSS handle its display. I'll add a note in the answer for you to try.