# image size not working in mozilla and IE

Tags: asp.net, image, css

I have a code which works fine in Google Chrome but not working in Firefox and IE.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass="image" />
```

**Css Code :**

```
.image{
 width:50px;
 height:50px; 
 content:url('Image.png'); 
}
.image:hover{
 width:50px;
 height:50px; 
 content:url('Image_Hover.png'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Different people here on SO were addressing the same issue. One solution was changing `content (...)` to `background-image`. In your case it would be: `background-image: url('Image.png');` (or with the hover picture)

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772960/css-hover-image-not-working-on-firefox-but-works-on-chrome) for more detail about that.
[Stuart Kershaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2332112/stuart-kershaw) gave an explanation for that behavior in one of the comments:

> I don't know why it works in Chrome, but the explanation for this is that you can't use the content attribute with the :hover selector. content is meant for :before/:after pseudo elements. –

Edit: Full example of your code, changed according to the information from the linked post:

```
 .image {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    display: block;
    background-image: url('Image.png');
}

.image:hover {
    background-image: url('Image_Hover.png');
}
```

Edit 2: If both images are of the same size, and you are decreasing their size with CSS every time to 50x50, you could just scale the image size to 50x50 and use the smaller images, so that you don't have to do it every time with CSS. I prefer using GIMP for that, but I bet there are many free online tools, which resize your image to the desired size.

Comment: i tried this background-image and its working find but image size not working how to do that

Comment: Are they different sized and you want to limit their size to 50px? Are they both the same size or is one image bigger than the other?

Comment: @no both are same size

Comment: did you use `display: block;`as well? Like it was stated in the linked post, it is important to set `display: block;`. Please see at my edited post.

Comment: FYI: Using `zoom` or `zoom-out` could also be used, but while `zoom`does not work for FF (and only not for Firefox), `zoom-out`does not workf for IE, Android, Safari and Opera. 
Source:
stackoverflow.com/questions/19772960/css-hover-image-not-working-on-firefox-but-works-on-chrome

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.my-img{
          width:100px;
          height:100px;
          background-image: url('Image.png');
        }
     .my-img:hover {
            background-image: url('Image_Hover.png');
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="my-img"></div>
```

> Try this.

Comment: You are using an ID. He instead wants to use it on a class.

Comment: You can also give class instead of id. add class attribute and replace "#" with ".". Works same. You can try.

Comment: Your previous version would not work for him, since he does not have those IDs. Basically classes and IDs are not the same, but yes, your example should work.

Answer (score 0):

There you haven't specify any floating position for the image. try `float:left` it will work